# Extracting Values from JSON using lens-aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson, haskell-lens

I just read the tutorial at https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms, and I have successfully written a query into a json bytestring.  However, I am not getting the kind of result value I want.

I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
if (j^? key "some key" == Just "Google") then ...
                                         else ...
```

But (j^? key "some key") has the type "Maybe Value".

This must be a common enough pattern that I'd be surprised if there wasn't a utility function to turn a Value into a Text.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is! The `_String` `Prism` has type `Prism' Value Text`, i.e. it attempts to traverse down the branch of `Value` containing a `Text`. So you can do `j ^? key "some key" . _String == Just "Google"`.

Answer (score 3):

My lens-fu is pretty limited, but looks like you need [`_String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens-aeson/0.1/doc/html/Control-Lens-Aeson.html#v%3a_String) method of `AsPrimitive`:

```
if (j^? key "some key" >>= (^? _String)) == Just "Google"
```

Or you can convert the right part to `Value`:

```
if (j^? key "some key" == Just (String "Google"))
```

Comment: `(_String.j ^? key "some key" == Just "Google")` should do the job.  Unfortunately, I can't test for stupid mistakes right here.

Comment: @Carl no, it doesn't, `j` is a `Value`, so `_String.j` doesn't make sense. I don't see the idea, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Oh.  Hah.  Yes, stupid mistakes.  The idea is that prisms compose, so you should be able to compose the `key "foo"` prism with the `_String` prism.  But the order should actually be `key "foo" . _String`, I think.

Comment: Yeah, `(j ^? key "some key" . _String)` works.  I finally got enough installed to test.

Comment: yes, it works now, thanks. PS the type of `key "foo" . _String` is terrible: `(Applicative f, Indexable Text p, AsValue t) =>
     p Text (f Text) -> t -> f t` :)

Comment: That terrible type just means `AsValue t => IndexedTraversal' t Text`. It's quite hard to translate lensey types, but you do get the hang of it. [Here](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Synonyms-by-Constraints) is a partial chart—though it doesn't include indexing.